# Numeric value not working with Solr Polish site

Tags: search

Using the Drupal 7.39 and Solr 3.5(Search Api module) keywords search works fine on Solr with the filter "StempelPolishStemFilterFactory" for the polish language.

But when using a numeric string like "18001g", "18010" the search return multiple records i.e. when searched for "18001" it returns the two record one of "18001" and "18010" ideally it should return one record i.e. "18001".

Using the Solr admin analysis feature, I found that the after the filter "StempelPolishStemFilterFactory" is applied the search value i.e. "18001" or "18010" changes to "180ć".

But in case if the above mentioned stemming filter is removed it effect the polish keywords searched.

Just need to under stand why this value changes and how to avoid this value changed or is there anyorder the filter needs to be placed.  Below is the polish configuration setting.

```
    enter code here
<fieldType name="text_pl" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt" />
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords_pl.txt" format="snowball" ignoreCase="true" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1"  catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" protected="protwords.txt" preserveOriginal="1" />
<filter class="solr.StempelPolishStemFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_pl.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
<filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt" />
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords_pl.txt" format="snowball" ignoreCase="true" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" protected="protwords.txt" preserveOriginal="1" />
<filter class="solr.StempelPolishStemFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
<filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```